# Ansible append text to line in certain section of INI file

Tags: linux, ansible

I would like to know if there is a way using Ansible to append text to the end of a line in certain section of a file, an example is going to clarify what I want to do:

Think of a file like this:

```
[section01]
path = /home/section01
read only = yes
list = yes
uid = apache
gid = apache
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
hosts allow = mexico,usa,canada

[section02]
path = /home/section02
read only = yes
list = yes
uid = apache
gid = apache
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
hosts allow = mexico,usa,canada

[section03]
path = /home/section03
read only = yes
list = yes
uid = apache
gid = apache
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
hosts allow = mexico,usa,canada
```

I would like to add "brazil" on host_allow in [section02] to get this "new file"

```
[section01]
path = /home/section01
read only = yes
list = yes
uid = apache
gid = apache
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
hosts allow = mexico,usa,canada

[section02]
path = /home/section02
read only = yes
list = yes
uid = apache
gid = apache
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
hosts allow = mexico,usa,canada,brazil

[section03]
path = /home/section03
read only = yes
list = yes
uid = apache
gid = apache
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
hosts allow = mexico,usa,canada
```

Comment: I usually tell my teammates to generate _ entire files_ with ansible because I've found solutions for updating the correct _part_ of a file tend to be unreliable when exposed to unanticipated file contents.  Some systems make this easier by allowing you to break up your config across multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

As @Dan Farrell mentioned in the comments, you are better off generating the entire file as partial updates can be unreliable, and problematic.

You can however use [ansible templates](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_templating.html) to accomplish this as well.

You create a template file(`file.ini` for example) with the contents below(removed other blocks for brevity). This file would contain the full INI file contents.

```
[section02]
path = /home/section02
read only = yes
list = yes
uid = apache
gid = apache
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
hosts allow = {{allow_hosts}}
```

Then, in your playbook, add a task to template this file.

```
- name: Template INI file
  template: 
    dest: "/path/to/some/file.ini" 
    src: file.ini 
    mode: 664 
    owner: root 
    group: root
```

When you instantiate the playbook, you can pass the full list of allowed hosts via `extra-vars`.

`ansible-playbook -i hosts --extra-vars="allow_hosts=mexico,usa,canada,brazil" my-playbook.yml`

This however will only work for you if you know all of the allowed hosts at the time the playbook is run.